# Folder and file names in a spreadsheet

Tags: batch-file

I was looking for a batchfile that could make a spreadsheet for all folder names at one location in 1st column and .xxx files in that folder in adjacent columns
eventually I would like to have a report that has folder name in first column and in each row corresponding .xxx file names in that folder

e.g. suppose folder_main has f1, f2, and so on and each folder has g1.xx, g2.xxx and so on
so report should show

```
 column1     column 2      column 3 ............
 f1           g1.xxx       g2.xxx   .....
 f2           h1.xxx.......
```

Could you please help me to write a batch file or a script in vb to perform this function. I have thousand of folders.

Comment: You can just generate a text file or a csv and then easily import it into any spreadsheet. What have you tried? what problems did you find?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a starting point for you that creates a CSV-style output. You should be able to open it in any spreadsheet program.

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('DIR /AD /B 2^> NUL') DO (
    SET line="%%A"
    FOR /F "delims=" %%B IN ('DIR %%A\*.xxx /B 2^> NUL') DO SET line=!line!,"%%B"
    ECHO !line!
)
```

I don't know how much you know about batch-scripting, so I leave it as-is for now. However, feel free to ask if something is unclear.

EDIT:
`EnableDelayedExpansion` is necessary to make the `!`-stuff work (see below).

The first `FOR`-line loops over all subdirectories in the current directory and throws away all possible error messages. The stuff between the `DO (` and `)` in the last line gets executed for each found subdirectory.

The `line`-variable will hold all files once the second `FOR`-loop has finished. It's initialised with the name of the subdirectory, i.e. the first column in the CSV-output.

That second `FOR`-loop looks for all files with extension `xxx` in the subdirectory found in the first loop and again throws away possible error messages. The `SET` appends the filenames to one another.

The `!` is used instead of `%`, which you may be familiar with. It applies the delayed expansion to the code (if you want more information about this run `SET /?` on your command line).

If you want to dig even deeper into the directory structure, you would need to add `/S` to the `DIR`-command in the first loop, e.g. `'DIR /AD /B /S 2^> NUL'`.

Comment: I do not know much about batch files. Could you please explain a bit how the code would work? would it also look into subfolders?